# RHEL 7 doing init 5 isolate graphical.target no graphical login screen, and nvidia

Tags: rhel, nvidia, console, graphics

using **RHEL 7.9 x86-64** on an HP server having a small nvidia GPGPU, a Tesla T4 if I remember correctly.  I do know this gpgpu is not a graphics card... it has no monitor outputs to it.

We currently have  `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` so the system boots to run level 3 with a text console.

We installed `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.57.02.run` from runlevel 3, seemed to be successful as we can run `nvidia-smi` and that shows normal output.

However when doing `init 5` or `systemctl isolate graphical.target` we remain in a single text window at the console, and doing `runlevel` reports `N 3 5`.

My question is:  since RHEL 7 no longer uses `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` this file is no longer there, how does console graphics and whatnot work?   What files where and how does all this graphics stuff happen now?

*I don't believe this console graphics problem is related to nvidia entirely as I have somehow created this problem on other servers not having any nvidia card or driver installed and have run into this same problem.  And we have everything working fine on numerous other servers having nvidia gpgpus and/or nvidia graphics card.*

**What does one do when doing `systemctl isolate graphical.target` does not result in a graphical console?**

This is on a 24" 1920x1200 monitor off the blue VGA port off the server motherboard.
Where if successful I can log in graphically and have terminal windows as well as mouse and copy/paste capability, but having no window and no mouse capability at the console is a show stopper and I am hoping to find a way to fix this without having to reinstall RHEL 7 from dvd.

*After installing RHEL 7.9 from dvd everything is initially fine, we somehow travel down some road we are not aware of where we nuke the graphical console*.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when GDM starts if the GPGPU has no monitor? Do you want to run Xorg on the GPU hooked up to the monitor (I assume an intel or MGA GPU)?  Do you want GDM to start but not run Xorg?

Comment: how do I work with GDM ?  **what files where?**  To your question- I expect GDM to fail; but the real problem is I don't know how to work with GDM in RHEL 7.  Can someone point me in the right direction so I can **begin** to understand what is happening?

Comment: I don’t understand what you want.  You want GDM to start… but fail?  Why not just use multi-user.target?

Comment: want a functional graphical console that will allow a user login and have a functioning window environment; I cannot have multi-user.target and a single 1970's text terminal I have software that needs installation and setup in a graphical environment (from the console) otherwise it is a show stopper.  All I know is "init 5" and the graphical console comes up on the monitor, if it does not and I am dead in the water left with reinstalling RHEL 7 from dvd to fix.  I would prefer to fix without reinstalling RHEL from dvd when this situation happens (from whatever causes it).

Comment: I want GDM to start, with no errors, and have a functional graphical console; somehow something has happened where graphical console fails and I have to ALT-F2  to get text console or boot single user mode and then only boot to multi-user.target from then on to have a functioning (albeit text) console.  I am lost when it comes to GDM (and xorg) configuration.

Comment: you need to configure Xorg to use whatever GPU you have the monitor hooked up to.  Do you know the device and PCI ID?  You’ll probably have to create a custom Xorg config entry for it.

Comment: You need to figure out why GDM is crashing.  Greg for “EE” in /var/log/gdm/*.log.  It should tell you what is wrong.

Comment: *you need to configure Xorg to use whatever GPU you have* ... this is what I do not understand.  RHEL 7 installed from dvd, GDM works out of the box and there is no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.   So how can this be?  It seems xorg is no longer being used by RHEL 7 (even if I install nvidia graphics driver) so I'm hoping to figure out how this is happening

Comment: RHEL 7 does use Xorg, but it is a lot smarter and so it doesn’t need a specific xorg.conf. The nvidia packages do include a config snippet in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/, and you will likely need to explicitly define a device, monitor and screen section there. Because xorg is “smart” I bet it detects the nvidia card and doesn’t like the lack of screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this stated in https://access.redhat.com/solutions/421683

The redhat solution only mentioned `mesa-libGL`
For reference this is what I did that was successful:

- unblacklist nouveau in `/etc/default/grub` followed by `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg`
- `rpm -ev --nodeps     mesa-libGLES mesa-libGLU mesa-libGL-devel mesa-dri-drivers mesa-libEGL-devel mesa-libEGL mesa-libxatracker mesa-libgbm mesa-libGLU-devel mesa-filesystem mesa-libOSMesa mesa-khr-devel mesa-libglapi mesa-libGLw mesa-libGL`
- `yum install  mesa* xorg-x11-drv-nouveau`
- `dracut -vf`
- `yum history sync` to remove yum altered outside warning.
- if using `dkms` do `dkms status` and be sure it responds empty regarding nvidia.
- reboot
- console graphics restored, as had been prior to installing nvidia or cuda.